# Flutter - Encountered a Error at an unrecoverable point. Failure was:

Tags: flutter, dart, domain-driven-design, bloc, flutter-bloc

I'm quite a newbie into the flutter_bloc and I got stuck for a couple of weeks with this issue and I didn't figure out how to solve it.

The problem that I have is that The BLocBuilder from AddressView it does not take into account the newly updated state.

From my undestanding is that the bloc state is updated to late since the BlocBuilder still takes the old value. (the empty value)

Class where the exception is thrown: AccountView.

In the BlocObserver the state changes correctly but when it reaches the BlocBuilder the initial value is taken into account and not the newly changed state with the initialized values.

CODE:

Bloc is Provided in the app_widget.dart , then I add an event to the satefull class AccountView -> and build the view. (Crashes on the BlocBuilder).

```
class AppWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  static const String title = 'Vault Pass';

  const AppWidget({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final _appRouter = getIt<AppRouter>();

    /// PROVIDES ACCESS TO BLOCS TO THE CHILDREN
    return MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
            create: (context) =>
                //adds event right away! with ..add()
                getIt<AuthBloc>()..add(const AuthEvent.authCheckRequest())),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => getIt<RegisterBloc>()),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => getIt<LoginBloc>()),
        BlocProvider(create: (context) => getIt<RecordBloc>()),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp.router(
        routerDelegate: _appRouter.delegate(),
        routeInformationParser: _appRouter.defaultRouteParser(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: title,
        theme: ThemeData(
            primaryColor: blackJet,
            //TODO: add colors here //splashColor: grey!!!,
            textTheme: GoogleFonts.poppinsTextTheme(Theme.of(context).textTheme),
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSwatch(primarySwatch: materialWhite),
            scaffoldBackgroundColor: blackFull),
      ),
    );
  }
}




class AccountView extends StatefulWidget {
  final Record record;

  const AccountView({required this.record, Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<AccountView> createState() => _AccountViewState();
}

class _AccountViewState extends State<AccountView> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    context.read<RecordBloc>().add(RecordEvent.initialized(fp.Option.of(widget.record)));
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocBuilder<RecordBloc, RecordState>(
      builder: (context, state) {
        return WillPopScope(
          /// this makes the device button work to go back
          onWillPop: () {
            context.navigateBack();
            return Future.value(false);
          },
          child: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Palette.blackFull,
            body: SafeArea(
              child: CustomScrollView(
                slivers: [
                  SliverFillRemaining(
                    hasScrollBody: false,
                    child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(8, 20, 8, 8),
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          //! RECORD TYPE
                          _RecordTypeWidget(value: state.record.type.value.toLowerCase()),
                          const Divider(height: 10, thickness: 1, color: Colors.white),
                          const SizedBox(height: 10),

                          //! RECORD NAME
                          ViewCardWidget(
                              textWidget: {"Record name": state.record.recordName.get()},
                              cardHeight: 12),

                          //! Title
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 10, 2),
                            child: Text("Credentials", style: bodyText(12, Palette.greySpanish)),
                          ),

                          //! RECORD LOGIN AND PASSWORD
                          ViewCardWidget(textWidget: {
                            "Login": state.record.loginRecord.get(),
                            "Password": state.record.passwordRecord.get()
                          }, cardHeight: 24),

                          //! URL
                          ViewCardWidget(
                              textWidget: {"Url": state.record.url.get()}, cardHeight: 12),

                          //! DESCRIPTION
                          ViewCardWidget(
                              textWidget: {"Description": state.record.description.get()},
                              cardHeight: 12),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
            floatingActionButtonLocation: FloatingActionButtonLocation.miniEndFloat,
            floatingActionButton: _SpeedDialFabWidget(recordId: state.record.id),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

---

You can clone the project from: https://github.com/gizet/vault_pass if you like to take a look.

Issue:

[image]

```
Stacktrace:
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following UnexpectedValueError was thrown building BlocBuilder<RecordBloc, RecordState>(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedProviderScope<RecordBloc?>], state: _BlocBuilderBaseState<RecordBloc, RecordState>#77787):
"Encountered a Error at an unrecoverable point. Failure was: MicroTypeFailure<String>.invalidString(failedValue: )"

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  BlocBuilder<RecordBloc, RecordState> BlocBuilder:file:///D:/_workspace/flutter/vault_pass/lib/presentation/view/records/account/account_view.dart:37:12
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      MicroType.get.<anonymous closure> (package:vault_pass/domain/microtypes/microtype.dart:15:30)
#1      Left.match (package:fpdart/src/either.dart:592:72)
#2      Either.fold (package:fpdart/src/either.dart:255:7)
#3      MicroType.get (package:vault_pass/domain/microtypes/microtype.dart:15:18)
#4      _AccountViewState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:vault_pass/presentation/view/records/account/account_view.dart:64:83)
#5      BlocBuilder.build (package:flutter_bloc/src/bloc_builder.dart:90:57)
#6      _BlocBuilderBaseState.build (package:flutter_bloc/src/bloc_builder.dart:166:21)
#7      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5080:27)
#8      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4968:15)
#9      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5133:11)
#10     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:5)
#11     StatefulElement.update (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5156:5)
#12     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3660:15)
#13     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4993:16)
#14     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5133:11)
#15     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4690:5)
#16     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2743:19)
#17     WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:863:21)
#18     RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:381:5)
#19     SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1289:15)
#20     SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:1218:9)
#21     SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:942:7)
#25     _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:192:26)
(elided 3 frames from class _Timer and dart:async-patch)
====================================================================================================
Reloaded 2 of 1556 libraries in 1,742ms (compile: 40 ms, reload: 338 ms, reassemble: 1243 ms).
D/EGL_emulation( 6445): app_time_stats: avg=53314.34ms min=53314.34ms max=53314.34ms count=1
```

Comment: The GitHub link is broken, presumably because the repo is private. But the top line of the error stack indicates that it's an issue at line 15 in the `package:vault_pass/domain/microtypes/microtype.dart` file, so you would want to start there.

Comment: Ops, sorry about that. Changed it to public. https://github.com/gizet/vault_pass . The issue is not that validation failure. The problem is the BlocBuilder that note take the updated state.   I think the RecordBloc somehow does not finish the job and the Builder takes the old value state and not the new.